# ASP.NET Core - How to resolve 'WebRequest.Create(string)' is obsolete: 'WebRequest, HttpWebRequest, ServicePoint, and WebClient are obsolete

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In ASP.NET Core-6 Web API Application, I am implementing Web Request for WSDL.

I have this code:

```
using System.Net;

private static HttpWebRequest CreateWebRequest(string url, string action)
{
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    webRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", action);
    webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
    webRequest.Accept = "application/xml";
    webRequest.Method = "POST";
    return webRequest;
}
```

But I got this error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning SYSLIB0014  'WebRequest.Create(string)' is obsolete: 'WebRequest, HttpWebRequest, ServicePoint, and WebClient are obsolete. Use HttpClient instead.'
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: The warning message suggests that you should use HttpClient instead of WebRequest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning message suggests that you should use HttpClient instead of WebRequest. The following method uses HttpClient to make a POST request to the specified url. It sets the SOAPAction header using the httpContent.Headers property. The PostAsync method returns an HttpResponseMessage object, which you can use to read the response from the server. You can then use the HttpResponseMessage object to read the response content or check the response status.

```
 using System.Net.Http;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;
 
 private static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> CreateWebRequest(string url, string action)
 {
      var httpClient = new HttpClient();
      var httpContent = new StringContent("", Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");
      httpContent.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", action);
      var httpResponse = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, httpContent);
      
      return httpResponse;
 }
```

Comment: Instead of using `new HttpClient()` consider using `IHttpClientFactory` to avoid the pitfalls of `HttpClient` (socket exhaustion, stale DNS caches, etc): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-7.0